# What is the purpose of Object[] es = elementData in Java Array List Implementation

Tags: java

In the Array List implementation, we have this snippet of code.
What is the purpose of the Object array? Why it is used and why not perform the operations on the elementData itself?

```java
int indexOfRange(Object o, int start, int end) {
        Object[] es = elementData;
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (es[i] == null) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (o.equals(es[i])) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe I've read somewhere that access to local variables is faster than to parameters - because of how they are located in memory.